# Getting value from a JSON

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps-api-3

I have a JSON like this --

```
  ....
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 37.42140090,
           "lng" : -122.08537010
        },
  ....
```

I am trying to access the lat and lng values. How can I do it?

My code

```
     results[0].geometry.location.lat
  or results[0].geometry.location.lng
```

does not work. But I get the output when I just use results[0].geometry.location .

The JSON I am using is -- http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=true

Update --

This is how I am making a request to the API

```
           geocoder.geocode( { 'address': search_addr}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                var t = results[0].geometry.location.lat;
            } else {
              alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
            }
```

Thanks

Comment: and what is `geometry` `datatype` i.e. its a `json` or `array`

Comment: Is that `or` actually in your code?  the rest of it looks correct.

Comment: What issue are you having? an error?

Comment: This is the out put I get ""function (){return this[a]}"" when I write alert(results[0].geometry.location.lat);

Comment: @Fox Can you share more of the related code? Are you making the request to Google API or have you copied the JSON as code? Something like http://jsfiddle.net/X844a/?

Comment: Note that `results` is a *property* of the `Object`. If the parsed JSON is stored in variable named `results`, the lookup may need to start as `results.results[0].geometry...` (for each the variable and property).

Comment: I am making a request to the Google API

Comment: Did you assign your json to a variable...??

Comment: I have updated the post with the code ..

Comment: I am basically making use of the code sample given here  -- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple

Comment: Just assign your JSON in a var and access it ..

Comment: I am not able to access the individual values .. that is if I do this alert(results[0].geometry.location) I get result as (36.311882, -119.6589889) but not able to access each of them ..

Comment: If it's a valid JSON , you will get [object Object] for alert(results[0].geometry.location) .. so please assign your JSON to a variable and access it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using Google's JavaScript APIs, you're not typically interacting with the parsed JSON directly, but rather with *wrapper* `Object`s.

Specifically, `results[0].geometry.location` will be an instance of [`google.maps.LatLng`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng). So, instead of holding the values themselves, `lat` and `lng` are methods that will `return` the values:

```
var geoLoc = results[0].geometry.location;
var lat = geoLoc.lat();
var lng = geoLoc.lng();
```

Comment: Thank you .. I also found out that I could access these values using the following code ""var lat = results[0].geometry.location.jb;
var lng = results[0].geometry.location.kb;" Which I though was strange .. But thanks a lot ..

Comment: @Fox You can. Those seem to be the "*private*" (or at least, internal-use) properties that `lat()` and `lng()` likely read from. But, if you do decide to use them, proceed with some caution. Since they aren't documented properties, there isn't really a guarantee they won't change.

Answer (score 5):

I tried your code with

```
alert(json.results[0].geometry.location.lat);
```

and it works as you can see in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/SWTZQ/

Comment: When I just do this alert(results[0].geometry.location) I get result as (36.311882, -119.6589889) but cannot access the individial elements